# Criteria for splitting of exact sequences of flat $R$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, arithmetic-geometry, group-schemes

Let $R$ be a complete local integral domain with fraction field $K= \operatorname{Frac}(R)$ and residue field $k=R/m$. Let

$$ 0 \to A_1 \to A \to A_2 \to 0 $$

a short exact sequence of finite, flat $R$-algebras. Assume that this sequence split as algebras after tensoring by $K$ and $k$. That means that for $T=F, k$ there exist a section, ie a morphism $s_T: A_2 \otimes_R T \to A \otimes_R T$ of $T$-algebras which induces ismorphisms of $T$-algebras $f_T: A_1 \otimes_R A_2 \otimes_R T \to A \otimes_R T$ compatible with the sequence.

And the question is if this data suffice to assure that the sequence above splits; ie that there exist section $s: A_2 \to A$ which induces isomorphism $f: A_1 \otimes_R A_2 \to A$ in compatible manner.

A natural choice for section $s$ is the composition $A_2 \hookrightarrow A_2 \otimes_R K \to A \otimes_R K$ und the hope is that lands exactly in $A \hookrightarrow A \otimes_R K$. Note that $A_2 \hookrightarrow A_2 \otimes_R K$ is injective is governed by our assumption on flatness. Moreover $s_k: A_2 \otimes_R k \to A \otimes_R k$ implies that modulo quotient by maximal ideal in $R$ the image of $A_2$ indeed lands in $A$ und this would induce the map $f:A_1 \otimes_R A_2 \to A$.

The injectivity follows from injectivity of $f_K$, surjectivity should follow from $f_k$.

The point where I'm still not very convinced if these considerations really suffice to assure that $A_2 \hookrightarrow A_2 \otimes_R K \to A \otimes_R K$ lands in $A$. Also, can this problem be approached more conceptionally, eg analyzing $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(A_2, A_1)$ groups, which as well known encode the information on extension classes of $A_1$ by $A_1$.

For example are there any canonical comparison maps relating $\operatorname{Ext}^1_R(A_2, A_1)$ to $\operatorname{Ext}^1_k(A_2 \otimes_R k, A_1 \otimes_R k)$, $\operatorname{Ext}^1_F(A_2 \otimes_R F, A_1 \otimes_R F)$ known, which could help to tackle this problem.

The described problem is related to an argument from [Arithmetic Geometry](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-8655-1), p 68. There originally the $A_i$ are Hopf-algebras und there it was indispensable to assume this to establish that $f_k$ is isomorphism.
But what if we assume now from the beginning that $f_K$ and $f_k$ are isomorphisms and our goal is to conclude from these assumptions that the sequence above split over $R$ or equivalently that $f$ is an isomorphism.

Should we still impose the Hopf algebra structure on $A_i$ and $A$, or is it at this stage not neccessary anymore and we obtain the desired splitting with pure homological algebra methods?

Comment: I am a bit confused by your mention of Ext groups, as $R$-algebas do not form an abelian category, and obviously there are no higher Ext groups for vector spaces over any field. Besides, these Ext groups would tell you about whether $A=A_1\oplus A_2$ is a direct sum, not a tensor product. In the reference you give, they have access to the notion of short exact sequence of groups, and splitting implying the middle term being a semidirect product. You are trying to define a ``short exact sequence of affine schemes over $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$" and ask when it's split, which seems much less natural.

Comment: Actually, note that $A_1$ cannot inject into $A$ as an ideal and a unital subalgebra unless $A=A_1$. If you take $A_1$ to be just a two sided ideal, then $ A_1\otimes A_2$ with the obvious product isn’t unital, and in particular isn’t $A$.

Comment: @StefanDawydiak: yes thanks, of course you're right, the goal should be to establish an iso
between $A_1 \otimes_R A_2$ and $A$; the direct sum $A_1 \oplus A_2$ is 
indeed meaningless here, and therefore the Ext group approach too.

There is also a notion of [Ext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension#Classifying_split_extensions)
for abstract groups which
governs the splitting property (as semidirect product) but 
I doubt that it can be applied in this situation to the associated
group schemes efficiently. Since a group scheme $G$ associates to a

Comment: $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$-
scheme $S$ a group $\mathrm{Hom}(S, G)=G(S)$ (the $S$-valued points)
, maybe there could be some ugly criterion on splitting of
$0 \to G^0 \to G \to G^{\text{ét}}  \to 0$ if for all 
$\mathrm{Spec}(R)$-schemes $S$ the Ext set
$\mathrm{Ext}(G^{\text{ét}}(S), G^0(S))$ vanishes. Nevermind, I don't know, that's
just a guess.

Comment: another question, you wrote that $A_1$ cannot be injected into $A$ as an
ideal (of $A$) and a unital subalgebra. But why should it be neccessary to 
require at this point that $A_1$ *is*
inject as an *ideal* in $A$? This aspect I not understand, could you lose few words on it?

Comment: There are no group schemes in your question the way there are in the reference you quote, because your $A_i$ are just algebras. You just have schemes, and that’s sort of the whole problem. As to why $A_1$ should be an ideal, it seems to me that the $0\to A_1\to A\to A_2\to 0$ is meant to exhibit that $A_1$ is a kernel and that the map is a map of algebras.